# how to convert svg to pdf using inkscape commande line linux?

Tags: python, linux, pdf, svg, inkscape

I'm trying to convert a svg file to pdf  by executing inkscape command line using python on linux like this :

```
result=subprocess.run(["inkscape",output_path+"/"+"final.svg","-export-area-drawing","--batch-process","--export-type=pdf","--export-filename="+output_path+"/"+"final.pdf"], capture_output=True, text=True)
```

but I have this :

(inkscape:108): WARNING **: 09:54:02.536: Invalid option --batch-process

Comment: Is inkscape a requirement or could you use an alternative like imagemagick?

Comment: yes I can use alternatives but It must generate a proper pdf. I tried some python moduls like svgcairo and svglib... but they dont generate proper pdf

Comment: Typo: It's `--export-area-drawing` with two leading dashes.

Comment: @ccprog that does not change any thing, the problem is in --batch process and --export-type

Comment: Which version of inkscape?

Comment: version Inkscape 1.1.2

Answer (score 0):

For me, this works, even though Inkscape segfaults after creating `outfile.pdf`, with complaints about three deprecated arguments:

`os.system("inkscape -D -z --file=infile.svg --export-pdf=outfile.pdf`